# ¿Qué puedo hacer para que se vean los estilos del navbar?

Tags: python, css, django

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando abro el index.html desde el navegador solo funciona perfecto, pero cuando lo heredo solo se puede ver el html sin los estilos:

```
{% extends 'base\index.html' %} 

{%block title%}Busqueda productos{%endblock%} 

{%block body%}

    <form action="/buscar/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="prd">
    <input type="submit" value="Buscar">

{%endblock%}
```

Comment: Adjunta el código de tu archivo `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

Verifica si la ruta relativa ha cambiado si es así aunque carges el html nunca tendrá acceso al css, para solventarlo tendrás que recalcular la ruta css o pornerla mas accesible desde un ámbito global MEDIA_URL=seria el path hasta llegar a la ruta de tu css

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}style.css">`

Comment: La forma en que vinculas los archivos estáticos no es la mejor ni la mas optima forma de hacerlo, para eso existe el *tamplate tag* [`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#static), que se encarga de vincular archivos estáticos que se guarda en [`STATIC_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATIC_ROOT), generando la URL de dicho archivo automáticamente. Te sugiero revisarlo, Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias recien estoy empezando a programar por eso las malas practicas, **¡voy a ver eso!**

Comment: Me gusta tu actitud, sigue aprendiendo! Suerte!